# Error with Javax.el dependency when deployed camel blueprint project in Karaf 4.4

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint

I have a blueprint project in camel version 2.23 - Java 8
When I try to deploy to Karaf 4.4, I am getting the following error with the javax.el dependency:

```
Camel Blueprint
Camel context "BaseRestContext"
Exception: Failed to create route SYNC-RESPONSE: Route(SYNC-RESPONSE)[[From[direct-vm:SyncResponse]] -> [OnEx... because of Failete Producer for endpoint: bean-validator://beanValidation. Reason: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initavax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route SYNC-RESPONSE: Route(SYNC-RESPONSE)[[From[direct-vm:SyncRes> [OnEx... because of Failed to create Producer for endpoint: bean-validator://beanValidation. Reason: javax.validation.Validation: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use MessageInterpolator instead
        at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:147)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3953)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3860)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3646)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3489)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3248)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3244)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3267)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3244)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3160)
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:255)
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:297)
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.blueprintEvent(BlueprintCamelContext.java:188)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:197)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:30
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: bean-validator://beanValidaton: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the ELcies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:584)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:160)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:1185)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.doStart(TryProcessor.java:163)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:160)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:104)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:80)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:370)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:196)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:145)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you haveependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMerpolator.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolato)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolatorConfiguredWithClassLoader(Confimpl.java:650)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:397)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:364)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.validator.ValidatorFactories.buildValidatorFactory(ValidatorFactories.java:63)
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.validator.BeanValidatorEndpoint.createProducer(BeanValidatorEndpoint.java:69)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:573)
        ... 63 more
```

I tried to add the following dependencies in the project pom file, but the problem continues

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
</dependency>
```

Also try replacing these dependencies and putting the latest version only, but the problem continues

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3</version>
   <!--<scope>compile</scope>
<type>jar</type> -->    
</dependency>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Remember - Maven dependencies are not what is actually available in Karaf when you install your blueprint bundle... I'd need much more information - how did you install Camel in Karaf 4.4? Camel version 2.23 is very old if used from Maven Central, but it is part of Red Hat Fuse 7 - are you using Fuse?

Comment: Camel 2.x is not compatible out of the box with latest Karaf 4.4.x.